# Restful API server did not find representation for target resource

Tags: java, tomcat

I am a C# Developer that built a very simple REST api only to be told i need to build it in java now..

So I said aight I got this but I am running into some issues.

I have a `Java Resources` folder with a `src` folder and inside that I have a `controllers` package and a `models` package along with a `calulcatorFunctions` package

Here is my CalculatorController.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
//import models.ResponseModel;
import models.RequestModel;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;

@Path("/ShippingCalculator")
public class CalculatorController {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // JSON
    public String InitializeCalculator(RequestModel JsonRequest) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInString = null;
        try 
        {
            jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(JsonRequest);

        } 
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonInString;
```

As you can see all im trying to do currently is return the POST body (json) back as a json string. eventually I will generate a response but baby steps for now.

The problem I have is when my app runs on the server, I am able to see my index.html at the default route (it simply says Hi)  however when i try to set a breakpoint on my controller method and call the path I get the error stated in the title in my web browser and my method is never entered..

Here is my web xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>ShippingCalculator</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShippingCalculator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>CalculatorController</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShippingCalculator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What kind of error? You never read errors in C# ecosystem? Also what path are you trying to access.

Comment: Its not an error its an http error, my method does not ever get entered is the problem.  I have tried localhost:8081/ShippingCalculator/ShippingCalculator, /api/shippingcalculator, /shippingcalculator/api/shippingcalculator and none enter my method. the only thing I get sucessfully is my index.html when i go to /shippingcalculator

Comment: edited my comment and yes I understand that caps is sensitive

Comment: have you tried localhost:8081/api/ShippingCalculator ? Also, how are you testing this?

Comment: How did you deploy your app?

Comment: I deployed my app by going to start>new project> dynamic web application.. I selected apache tomcat 9 as my server

Comment: Probably your request is not mapped correctly due to the absence of `"Content-Type: application/json"` or `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

Comment: And your package is `CalculatorController` just like that ? You have ommited package declaration so its hard to tell what is the actual package (or maybe you are using default package?)

Comment: Sorry im not up to date on most conventions, i created a new package and name it simply 'controller' and 'models' in the 'src' folder

Comment: I am asking becauze here `<param-value>CalculatorController</param-value>` you should put package where all your controllers are. So maybe it should be `controller ` not `CalculatorController`

Comment: OOH maybe this is it, I will test this thank you for the headsup